# Recover specific directory deleted in ntfs hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ntfs

I need  recover a directory deleted after cut to external device. I lost this data and I didn't  any more in my hard drive after cut the data.

So I saw ntfsundelete and now try to use this command. I saw this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/425091/387452) in other similar question, that they use extundelete command and it has an option for restore a specific directory.

```
sudo extundelete --restore-directory /home/Documents/ /dev/sda1
```

Is it possible do something similar with ntfsundelete? I accept too others ways different of ntfsundelete, but keep in mind that I need to find some directories and recover the complete directory. **Importan the hard drive is an NTFS volume.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @mikewhatever Maybe you don't see my point, if you read my question you can see that I looking for a similar option like extundelete in ntfsundele, I know that extundelete is for FS based in ext

Comment: @mikewhatever if this option  is not possible with `ntfsundelete` I appreciate another option, but note that I need to recover is a directory

Comment: @mikewhatever Sorry If I have some grammatical errors, I try to fix this now, ok thanks something like your answer is that I need, but is it not possible with any other tool?

Comment: Hold on, I didn't see that you meant ntfsundelete, my mistake. Let us start again. It should be possible to recover something. According to the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/ntfsundelete.8.html), you could try `ntfsundelete scan /dev/sdXY`, and see what happens.

Comment: Just using Testdisk would be easier...

Comment: Using TestDisk, click through device and type to Advanced.. in partition selection, pay attention to the bottom for Undelete. Then select a different drive to save to. I believe its possible to write a script using fls from TestDisk to recover from a single directory if that is needed or when the TD single selection is tedious.. see this answer here: unix.stackexchange.com/a/390174/346155